# écriture inclusive "cela lui permettra ..."

Tags: pronoms-personnels, écriture-inclusive

J'écris un texte à propos d'une personne non-binaire. Dans la phrase suivante:

> Cela lui permettra de ...

Est-ce que le mot "lui" dans ce contexte devrait être modifié pour respecter l'écriture inclusive ? En quoi ?

Comment: *lui* s'emploie déjà sans distinction de genre dans cette position. « C'est Carine, on peut lui faire confiance, à elle. »

Comment: @LukeSawczak Tout à fait. "Lui" reste un mot à connotation largement masculine qui m'aurait paru cohérent de remplacer par un équivalent non-genré. "Leur" a été proposé par chatGPT mais ne me semble pas idéal.

Comment: Oui, c'est vrai. C'est peut-être parce que ce suis anglophone et que j'ai dû apprendre de façon explicite à divorcer le mot d'avec sa connotation masculine (à considérer le mot comme *pouvant* en être divorcé) que j'ai cette réaction... D'ailleurs, je partage ton avis sur "leur".

Comment: Ma réaction initiale avait été _leur_ aussi, mais je ne l'ai pas soumis, car il m'a semblé que c'était plutôt pour un pluriel.

Comment: On comprends pourquoi les anglophones pensent à *leur*, parcre que le pluriel *their* est souvent utilisé pour dégenrer les pronoms . Mais ici *lui* convient parfaitement.

Answer (score 4):

Dans cette tournure (pronom conjoint) *lui* est la seule forme qu'on emploie au singulier, que ce soit pour un homme que pour une femme.

Il ne me semble donc pas qu'il faille faire un cas particulier ici.

Answer (score 2):

Peut-être: *cela permettra à cette personne de ...*, quoique cela ne soit pas une nécessité (cf. jlliagre's answer and Luke's comment).

Answer (score 1):

En supposant qu'on parle de Dominique par exemple,

> cela **lui** permettra de XXX

est équivalent à

> cela permettra **à Dominique** de XXX"

Comme "lui" remplace "à Dominique" et pas simplement "Dominique", ça ne dépend pas du genre de Dominique. On écrira "lui" que Dominique soit un homme, une femme, ou n'importe qui d'autre.

La question du genre de Dominique peut se poser dans d'autres cas, par exemple:

> Mon téléphone a sonné, j'ai décroché... et c'était Dominique !

dans ce cas le pronom devra être accordé:

> Mon téléphone a sonné, j'ai décroché... et c'était **elle** ! (si Dominique est une femme)

> Mon téléphone a sonné, j'ai décroché... et c'était **lui** ! (si Dominique est un homme)

Pour les personnes non-binaires il n'y a pas de consensus officiel sur le pronom à utiliser dans ce cas mais le plus courant est "ellui" (d'autres options existent aussi mais à ma connaissance sont très peu utilisés)